# Where exactly can I access IB auto generated layout constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, autolayout

I have a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell` that seems to have `NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraints` auto generated by IB.

It doesn't look like I can actually access the constraints by calling `myLabel.constraints` or `myCell.constraints`.

Is it stored somewhere else or am I just not able to access this through code?

Comment: Are they maybe in the cell's `contentView` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a custom table cell (that is, you dragged the UILabel from the objects library to the table cell), then select the UILabel in IB. In the bottom right-hand corner of the IB canvas, click the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" button--it looks like a Tie-Fighter from Star Wars. From the pop-up menu, choose "Add Missing Constraints". This should show the automatically generated constraints. You can re-configure them in IB and make outlets to them.

If you are using a UILabel that comes with one of those pre-configured table cells (e.g., Basic Style), then you might not be able to re-configure the label's constraints. For the UILabel in a pre-configured cell, the "Add Missing Constraints" item is disabled.

If you want to modify the constraints of a UILabel in a pre-configured table cell, then you might consider using a custom style table cell instead.